# BxSlider maxslide and minslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

So basically, i am using BxSlider with 27 thumbnails, on each is loaded a lightbox so you can check every image.

Thing is, when i load the script with this :

```
$('ul#items').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 5,
          maxSlides: 5,
          slideWidth: '920px'
        });
```

I am forced to get 5 thumbnails on everypage of the slider.
So on the last page, my last 3 thumbnails are the first 3 repeated.

I tried using this, instead to fix my problem,

```
$('ul#items').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 5,
          slideWidth: '920px'
        });
```

But it seems that if you input 1 as minSlides, the script will put only 1 (which gives you 27 pages of 1 thumbnail) slide per page, even if you specefy a maximum of 5 per slide.

Any way to fix this issue ?
thanks alot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [example 3](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example3) it describes the issue you are having. Because the slideWidth property is set to be larger than the container it defaults to the minSlide property to allow the slides to scale.

> "Here we intentionally set a slideWidth larger than the available space. In this case, the slider defaults to the minSlide value, and scales appropriately." - bxslider example 3 description

To get the desired effect you are looking for you should set the max-width value as the slideWidth property. This way the screen will allow you to switch between minSlide and maxSlide as the viewport allows. You can see this demonstrated in [example 4](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example4).

I hope this helps, as it took me a while to figure out for myself.

```
$('ul#items').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('ul#items').bxSlider({
          minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 5,
          slideWidth: '920px',
          infiniteLoop: false
        });
```